# Scala case class copy only with some parameters at runtime?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play Framework and client can send only some fields to update in database. Then I need to do something like this:

```
   g.copy(
      partnumber = jGood.partnumber,
      cost = jGood.cost
      )
```

So, most of the fields I will have in `jGood` will be `None` and only some of them will be `Some`. Now how can I filter all those `None` fields and make a copy of class only with `Some` fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this:

```
g.copy(
  partnumber = jGood.partnumber.orElse(g.partnumber),
  cost = jGood.cost.orElse(g.cost)
)
```